# How to get start & end of same week last year in DB2 using SQL?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a weekly report that uses these date parameters:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TABLE
WHERE   DATE_FIELD BETWEEN (CURRENT DATE - 8 DAYS) AND (CURRENT DATE - 2 DAYS)
```

This runs on Mondays to gather the previous week's data (Sun-Sat). What I want now is to run this for the same week of the previous year.

So for example, if the code above runs on Mon 29/06/20, it returns data from Sun 21/06/20 - Sat 27/06/20, i.e. week 26 of 2020. I want it to return data from Sun 23/06/19 - Sat 29/06/19, i.e. week 26 of 2019.

The report runs automatically so I can't just plug in the exact dates each time. I also can't just offset the date parameters to -357 and -367 days, as this gets thrown off by leap years.

I've searched for solutions but they all seem to rely on the DATEADD function, which my DB2 database doesn't recognise.

Does anyone know how I can get the result I'm looking for, please? Any advice would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to build a calendar or dates table...(google `sql calendar table`)

Among the columns you'd have would be

- date
- year
- month
- quarter
- dayofWeek
- startOfWeek
- endOfWeek
- week_nbr

You can use the week() or week_iso() functions when loading the table, pay attention to the differences and pick the best fit for you.

Such a calendar table makes it easy to compare current period vs prior period.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that all years have 52 weeks, you can use date arithmetic:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TABLE
WHERE   DATE_FIELD BETWEEN (CURRENT DATE - (8 + 364) DAYS) AND (CURRENT DATE - (2 + 364)  DAYS)
```

Because you want the week to start on a Monday, this doesn't have to take leap years into account.  It is subtracting exactly 52 weeks -- and leap years do no affect weeks.

This gets more complicated if you have to deal with 52 or 53 week years.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit complicated, but it should work. You may run it as is or test your own date.

```
SELECT 
  YEAR_1ST_WEEK_END + WEEKS_TO_ADD * 7 - 6 AS WEEK_START
, YEAR_1ST_WEEK_END + WEEKS_TO_ADD * 7     AS WEEK_END
FROM
(
SELECT
  DATE((YEAR(D) - 1)||'-01-01')
+ (7 - DAYOFWEEK(DATE((YEAR(D) - 1)||'-01-01'))) AS YEAR_1ST_WEEK_END
, WEEK(D) - 2 AS WEEKS_TO_ADD
FROM (VALUES DATE('2020-06-29')) T(D)
);
```

The intermediate column `YEAR_1ST_WEEK_END` value is the 1-st Sat (end of week) of previous year for given date.
`WEEKS_TO_ADD` is a number of weeks to add to the `YEAR_1ST_WEEK_END` date.